# How can I use multiple ISPs to increase bandwidth and redundancy for my website?

Tags: load-balancing, windows-server-2012, static-ip, round-robin, wide-area-network

I have an HTTP server behind Microsoft load balancing.  DNS is provided by the hosting provider.

I want to increase the available bandwidth by adding another internet ISP.

How can I ensure availability when one carrier is down?

What kind of router do I need?

How can the servers remain on line if the static IP is provided by a specific carrier?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to properly handle multiple lines you have two options.

**First Option**

Set up your DNS with a very low TTL for the domain, when the primary connection goes down, update this with the IP given to you by the second ISP. This of course is manual, it might be possible to set up something with DYDNS, and some monitoring scripts.

**Second Option**

Do it properly and obtain an AS number and your own IP address range. You can then have your IP range made reachable from both connections from multiple ISPs (possibly even more than 2). This does cost money and time, but it is a much more stable and permanent solution.

Comment: what is an AS number? how can i obtain it?

Comment: can i buy another router another  isp line another  static ip another  nic and add the second ip to host provider dns configuration panel?
is it another solution?

Comment: An AS number is an Autonomous System number, basically it identifies you as a piece of the internet, not just a user connected to an ISP.  read a bit more here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_(Internet)

Comment: As for your second solution, it will work, but if you do something like round robin DNS, the DNS doesn't know if a line is up or down, so it will give out address 1, or 2, and if that line is down, the site is unavailable for that user.. so it really isn't a solution which will increase your availability.

Comment: why you have closed the question?

Comment: Please read the FAQ.

Comment: i've read the FAQ but still don't understand why you close my question, i suppose it is too intelligent for your site standards

Comment: No, it's just not any more answerable than what has already been posted. It's a very vague question, if you added more detail, for example your first question has multiple answers, therefor it's impossible to answer the second question until you decide on one course of action and the third is only a valid question in some of the scenarios that the first question brings up. Fix that and we will try to properly answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ensure availability when one carrier is down?

Get a router that supports active/active load balancing of outbound connections.

> What kind of router do I need?

One that meets your needs. Call your preferred vendor like Cisco, Juniper, Extreme, etc and ask them what products they have in your price range for your requirements.